# How to create multiple buttons to change a shortcode inline

Tags: javascript, wordpress, shortcode

I have a number of photo galleries created in my WordPress site, but I only want to show one at a time.  I'm trying to create a series of buttons / hyperlinks that will change which gallery is displayed in a page (not a popup page).

I've tried the following (each `<li>` is a different attempt) but nothing is working for me.  Can anyone help?

```
<ul>
  <li><a onClick="document.getElementById('showMe').innerHTML = '[foogallery id=123]'">Gallery 1</a></li>
  <li><a onClick="document.getElementById('showMe').innerHTML = '<?php echo do_shortcode( \'[foogallery id=234]\' ); ?>'">Gallery 2</a></li>
  <li><a href="<?php echo do_shortcode( '[foogallery id=345]' ); ?>" target="showMe" >Gallery 3</a></li>
</ul>
<div id="showMe"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

if I understand you correctly, try this code

HTML

```
<div class="gallery-change-btn">
  <button class="btn" data-gallery-id="id-yougallery">Gallery #1</button>
  <button class="btn" data-gallery-id="id-yougallery">Gallery #2</button>
  <button class="btn" data-gallery-id="id-yougallery">Gallery #3</button>
</div>
```

HTML gallery

```
<div class="wrapper-gallery">
  <div id="foogallery-gallery-1" class="gallery">qwe1</div>
  <div id="foogallery-gallery-2" class="gallery">qwe2</div>
  <div id="foogallery-gallery-3" class="gallery">qwe3</div>
</div>
```

JS

```
<script>
  jQuery('.gallery-change-btn').on('click', 'button' , function(){
    var element = jQuery(this).data('gallery-id');
    jQuery('.wrapper-gallery .gallery').each(function (key, value) {
      if (jQuery(value).attr('id') === ('foogallery-gallery-'+element)) {
        jQuery(value).show();
        return;
      }else{
        jQuery(value).hide();
      }
    });
  });
</script>
```

And you need wrap your gallery in `wrapper-gallery`class

Comment: Thanks for your prompt response.  I'm a novice at javascript - how do I get the results of your jQuery to show up on my page?  I tried `<div class="wrapper-gallery"></div>` but I obviously need more than that.

Comment: I'm sorry I don't understand your request.  What else do I need to add to my page to display the gallery?  I know I need to wrap the gallery with `<div class="wrapper-gallery"></div>` but what else?

Comment: @timhuk Add buttons above the gallery, and js code. That's all

Comment: I appreciate your help, but I just can't get your code to work.  All galleries are displayed all of the time and the buttons are not working.   However you have taught me that rather than create the shortcode on the fly from a button click, I should code all gallery shortcodes and use the buttons to show/hide these.  To this end I'm using [this](http://blogs.html5andcss3.org/show-and-hide-multiple-div-using-javascript/) method.